# Use data-attribute values to select form fields and autofill from MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to succeed with populating dynamically generated form fields from a database via xmlhttp. First row is "static" and when I type in the SKU-field the name[] field gets the data correct from the database. When I click the "#addrow" button a new row is added and here I want to be able to type in the SKU-field and have the name[] field get data from the database. Right now what happens is that the row above gets updated when I type in the SKU-field.

I have added data-attributes for the SKU-field and name-field and also a counter so I somehow could select the field data-names and from this be able to parse the value to the right name-field in the right row?

I have tried to add a variable and see if I can get this to parse the database value to the right name-field, but it does not work:

```
var field = "name" + $(this).attr("data-dynid");
field.value = myObj[0];
```

I just need to figure out how to have the code recognize which SKU-field I am typing in (with the data-attribute counter) and from the counter select the name-field with the same counter value.

*** UPDATE ****

So I found a way to locate a form field from data-attribute and assign a value to it. Now I need to figure out how to have the code recognize the SKU field I am typing in, in order to retreive the SKU data-attribute number and use this dynamically to locate the form field to parse the data to.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dynname="name-1"]');
elements[0].value = myObj[0];
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="inputFormRow">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                          <label class="form-control-label" for="sku">Varenummer</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control searchInput"  name="sku[]" placeholder="Varenummer" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="GetDetail(this.value)" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                          <label class="form-control-label" for="name">Navn</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control name"  name="name[]" placeholder="Navn" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                          <label class="form-control-label" for="content">Tekst</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="text[]" placeholder="Tekst" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                          <label class="form-control-label" for="normalprice">Normalpris</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="beforeprice[]" placeholder="Normalpris" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                          <label class="form-control-label" for="offerprice">Tilbudspris</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="offerprice[]" placeholder="Tilbudspris" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                          <label class="form-control-label" for="size">Størrelse</label>
                          <select class="form-control"  name="size[]" placeholder="Størrelse" autocomplete="off">
                              <option value="A4" selected="">A4</option>
                              <option value="A5">A5</option>
                              <option value="A10">A10</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                          <label class="form-control-label" for="removeRow">&nbsp;</label>               
                              <button id="removeRow" type="button" class="form-control btn btn-danger">Fjern</button>
                            
                        </div>
                      </div>
                
            </div>

            <div id="newRow"></div>
            <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add Row</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // add row
    var counter = 1;
    $("#addRow").click(function () {
        
        var html = '';
        html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';

        html += '<div class="row">';
        html += '<div class="form-group col-md-2">';
        
        html += '<input type="text" class="form-control searchInput" data-dynid ="' + counter + '"  name="sku[]" placeholder="Varenummer" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="GetDetail(this.value)">';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div class="form-group col-md-4">';
        
        html += '<input type="text" class="form-control name" data-dynname ="name-' + counter + '" name="name[]" placeholder="Navn" autocomplete="off">';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div class="form-group col-md-2">';
        
        html += '<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="text[]" placeholder="Tekst" autocomplete="off">';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div class="form-group col-md-1">';
        
        html += '<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="beforeprice[]" placeholder="Normalpris" autocomplete="off">';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div class="form-group col-md-1">';
        
        html += '<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="offerprice[]" placeholder="Tilbudspris" autocomplete="off">';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div class="form-group col-md-1">';
       
        html += '<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="size[]" placeholder="Størrelse" autocomplete="off">';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div class="form-group col-md-1">';
                    
        html += '<button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-danger removeRow">Fjern</button>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        $('#newRow').append(html);
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
    });

    // remove row
    $(document).on('click', '.removeRow', function () {
        $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
    });
</script>
    <script>
  
        // onkeyup event will occur when the user 
        // release the key and calls the function
        // assigned to this event
        function GetDetail(str) {
            if (str.length == 0) {
                document.getElementsByName("first_name")[0].value = "";
                                
                return;
            }
            else {
  
                // Creates a new XMLHttpRequest object
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  
                    // Defines a function to be called when
                    // the readyState property changes
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && 
                            this.status == 200) {
                          
                        // Typical action to be performed
                        // when the document is ready
                        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        
                        
                        // Returns the response data as a
                        // string and store this array in
                        // a variable assign the value 
                        // received to first name input field
                        //var el = document.getElementsByName('name[]')[0];  
                        //var el = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
                        //var r2 = console.log(el).closest("name[]");
                        document.getElementsByName("name[]")[0].value = myObj[0];
                        //r2.value = myObj[0];                          
         
                    }
                };
  
                // xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "pages/actions/load-products.php?user_id=" + str, true);
                  
                // Sends the request to the server
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
    </script>
```